# Is there a way to nest Flask variables (url_for) when passing to an HTML template? (Python)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to template some of my common HTML elements by passing them as Flask variables, specifically my stylesheets and scripts.  For further simplification and responsiveness I'm trying to use `url_for` to connect those.

In my app.py I have:

```
common_html = {
   'navbar': '''<nav class....>''',
   'scripts': '''<!-- D3 -->
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Personal JS -->
        <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='javascript/myjs.js')}}"></script>'''
}

@app.route('/index')
def index():
   return render_template('index.html', common=common_html)
```

And in my HTML file:

```
...
<body>
   <!-- Nav --!>
   {{common['navbar']|safe}}
   <h1>Stuff</h1>
</body>
<!-- Scripts -->
{{common['scripts']|safe}}
</html>
```

In browser, my navbar code loads perfectly fine, however the script tag containing the url_for statement is not run properly.  It appears as is `<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='javascript/myjs.js')}}"></script>` upon inspection.  The script file is in the proper directory/filepath.

I've tried removing the `{{}}` double brackets and messing with the different quotations used to no avail.  I have memory of this method working at some point previously, but can't say for certain.

Is there a practice or way to use url_for within a block of template code or is this poor practice?  Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: It is the correct way but there's also a browser cache. Did you clear that?

Comment: Separately, why are you passing the navbar on each request? It doesn't make sense to my why you're passing the navbar _or_ an import

Comment: Does `|safe` have anything to do with whether or not jinja will recognise the double braces?

Comment: @roganjosh I did not try clearing the browser cache, but I have been doing hard reloads in between changes.  What would clearing do?

Comment: @roganjosh I'm passing the navbar because it's shared between multiple .html files, passing it in a variable is quick and simple especially if I ever need to make changes to it -- its all in one place.

Comment: @monsieuralfonse64 I don't have a complete understanding of `|safe`, however it is required to escape the triple quotes.

Comment: Why don't you have a base template and use template inheritance? It's not something to be passed on each request

Comment: @roganjosh That's probably a smarter way of doing things! I didn't realize I would have so many html pages when I started so I don't think it crossed my mind.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason for this is that jinja doesn't render anything *inside* something that's already being rendered. So because you are passing the `{{ url_for() }}` inside a double brace, it will automatically escape anything in it. What you've basically done is put Jinja syntax in something that isn't evaluated by Jinja. So it actually looks like this:

`{{ "{{ url_for() }}" }}`.

Remember, Jinja will just put whatever's in the first double braces onto the page (after escaping), so it doesn't render the actual value of that `{{url_for()}}`. I would recommend using a base template which can then be inherited by your other pages.

Comment: That seems to be the consensus from some of the other comments too.  I'll switch things over to a base template.  So there's no way for this to work then?

Comment: @JoshLowy It is much better practice to have template inheritance, but I'm sure you could find a way to make it work if you desperately wanted to. For example, instead of placing the double braces surrounding `url_for()` in the `common` dictionary, you could just concatenate the actual value of the url. Like so: `"scripts":"<script src="+url_for('static', filename='my.js')+"></script>`

Comment: That's broken, you can't drop the `{{}}`

Comment: Ignore me. I forgot they were passing a string that doubled down on the jinja formatting. Sorry

Comment: @roganjosh don't worry, it's an odd way to do it so no wonder it gets confusing. I really think template inheritance would be a lot better, mainly because it's just simpler.